# Read a file locked for writing

Tags: java, locking

I use file lock as a means to prevent several executions of my app:

```
FileLock lock = fc.tryLock();
if (lock == null) {
    System.out.println("Error: The process is already running.");
}
```

So far so good. Now I would like to write another process that would be able to kill the first one.
I would like to write the current PID in the lock file. The second process would verify the lock is here (meaning the process is running), read the file and kill the PID. Verifying the lock before reading is mandatory because the OS may recycle PIDs: the main process may be stopped and its PID reused  by another process. Problem is reading the file is impossible due to the lock (while I thought lock would only prevent to write...)

Here a simplified code:

```
public class TestLock {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 1 && "kill".equals(args[0])) {
            kill();
        } else {
            run();
        }
    }

    private static void run() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("test.lock");
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            FileLock lock = fos.getChannel().tryLock();
            if (lock == null) {
                System.err.println("Error: The process is already running.");
            } else {
                int pid = Integer.parseInt(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().split("@")[0]);
                System.out.println("Process is launched with PID = " + pid);
                fos.write(String.valueOf(pid).getBytes("UTF-8"));
                while(true) {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.out.println("App is running");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void kill() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("test.lock");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.err.println("Error: The process is not running.");
            return;
        }
        try (FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(file.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
            FileLock lock = fc.tryLock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, true);
            if (lock == null) {
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
                fc.read(bb);
                String pid = new String(bb.array(), "UTF-8").trim();
                System.out.println(pid);
                // Kill the process
            } else {
                System.err.println("Error: The process is not running.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the app twice without argument, the second instance displays "Error: The process is already running." If I try to kill the process while it is not running, I get "Error: The process is not running." But if I try to kill the running process, I get an IOException "The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file"

Seeing in other threads that locks would only be advisory (not really locking if not checked, if I understood properly), I tried removing the lock check and use a simple FileReader in the kill method, but I get the same error. (and anyway, I would rather not do that because of the PID reuse, as stated earlier)